# Determine the smallest 3D cuboid which entirely contains a domain-restricted parametric curve

Tags: calculus, curves, parametric

If I have a parametric cubic curve in 3 dimensions defined by:

$$\vec r(t) = \vec At^3 + \vec Bt^2 + \vec Ct + \vec D$$ where $t\in [0; 1]$, how can I determine the co-ordinates of the smallest 3D cuboid $\vec P_1$ and $\vec P_2$ that entirely contain the curve over this domain?

To my understanding, each dimension is entirely independent, and so my idea is to do the following, but I am not sure if it is entirely correct/if there is a better way. For each dimension:

- Find the derivative and set to 0 to determine any local maxima and minima in the domain
- Determine the co-ordinate of the endpoints of the domain
- Determine the minimum and maximum of all the values obtained above
- Use these two values (min and max) as the scalar component for that dimension of $\vec P_1$ and $\vec P_2$ respectively

Thereby obtaining a set of minimums and maximums defining the two opposite corners of a cuboid.

Would this work?

Comment: Must the cube be parallel to the coordinate axis? (If not, the problem could be pretty difficult). Also, must it be a cube of is it enough with a rectangular cuboid? Your method seems to give a rectangular cuboid

Comment: Yes, I meant a cuboid. Would my method work if the cube needed to be parallel to the axis? If it didn't need to, how could I go about doing it?

Comment: If the cuboid needs to be parallel to the axis yes, your method works. If not, the only way I can think of is to parametrize the possible orthonormal bases of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then work out the smallest cuboid parallel to the vectors of each base (using your method), and find the base in which the volume of the cuboid is the least. This would lead to very complex calculations, including divisions in cases and such.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguez luckily I've just determined that it does need to be parallel, so I don't have to go there! haha. Thanks for the help